# Avoid duplicate values in foreach laravel session array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hi i need to solve this case in session cart that have array in session

> The size duplicated many times in blade like this

> Size:
> large
> large
> large

```
array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "quantity" => 36
    "color_items" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "color" => "3"
        "size" => "2"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "color" => "2"
        "size" => "2"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "color" => "1"
        "size" => "2"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

```
<dl class="card-item-desc-1">
<dt>Size:</dt>                                                                @foreach($details['color_items'] as $de)
<dd>
{{  \App\Models\Size::find($de['size'][0])->name }}
</dd>
@endforeach
</dl>
```

Comment: I really hope that you will edit the question with more information and a detailed description of the problem :) By the way, using a ```models``` call in the ```view``` is a bad practice. Very.

Comment: @HopexDevelopment Size: large large large
will duplicate like this

Comment: You have missed part of the foreach loop so its hard to help you

Comment: @foreach($details['color_items'] as $de)
<dd>
{{  \App\Models\Size::find($de['size'][0])->name }}
</dd>
@endforeach

Comment: @ColinMD not missed anything

Comment: Apologies, the foreach has jumped across to the right. so needed to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

First strip the size out of the color_items array and use as its own array.

Second would be to use the power of collections

Change the foreach to

```
@foreach(collect($details['color_items'])->pluck('size')->unique() as $size)
<dd>
{{  \App\Models\Size::find($size)->name }}
</dd>
@endforeach
```

So what we are doing is adding the color_items to a collection, taking only the size field and then making sure its unique.

Hope that helps